# How to create custom form in Magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2, forms

I like to add custom form with submit button. After submitting the form I need to get details to my email.
Please let me know how to start.

Thanks in advance.

Okay i created Returns/Cform/registration.php

```
php?
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register( 
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 
'Returns_Cform', 
__DIR__ 
);
```

Returns/Cform/Controller/Index/index.php

```
namespace Returns\Cform\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends Action
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }   
    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();       
        $data = $objectManager->create('Returns\Cform\Model\Cform');
        $data->setData($post);
        $data->save();
         echo "hello";
        exit; 

        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Form successfully submitted'));

    }
}
```

Returns/Cform/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Returns_Cform" setup_version="2.2.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

Returns/Cform/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="cform" frontName="cform">
            <module name="Returns_Cform" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Returns/Cform/Model/Cform.php

```
<?php

namespace Returns\Cform\Model;

class Cform extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Returns\Cform\Model\ResourceModel\Cform');
    }

}
```

Returns/Cform/Model/ResourceModel/Cform.php

```
<?php

namespace Returns\Cform\Model\ResourceModel;

class Cform extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    protected $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        $connectionName = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $connectionName);
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('returns_contect', 'contect_id');
    }
}
```

Returns/Cform/Model/ResourceModel/Cform/Collection.php

```
<?php
namespace Returns\Cform\Model\ResourceModel\Cform;

use \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{

    protected $_idFieldName = \Returns\Cform\Model\Cform::CONTECT_ID;

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Returns\Cform\Model\Cform', 'Returns\Cform\Model\ResourceModel\Cform');
    }

}
```

Return/Cform/Setup/InstallSchema.php

```
<?php
namespace Returns\Cform\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        /**
         * Create table 'returns_contect'
         */
        $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
            $installer->getTable('returns_contect')
        )->addColumn(
            'contect_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'Contect Id'
        )->addColumn(
            'name',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Name'
        )->addColumn(
            'email',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Email Id'
        )->addColumn(
            'telephone',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['nullable'=> false],
            'Phone Number'
        )->addColumn(
            'order_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            null,
            ['nullable'=> false],
            'Order ID'
        )->addColumn(
            'product',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            null,
            ['nullable'=> false],
            'Product Name'
        )->addColumn(
            'quantity',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['nullable'=> false],
            'Quantity'
        )->addColumn(
            'opened',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            null,
            ['nullable'=> false],
            'Product is opened'
        )->addColumn(
            'comment',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Reason for Return'
        );
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
    }
}
```

Return/Cform/view/frontend/layout/contactform_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Returns\ContactForm\Block\Form" name="contactForm" template="Returns_ContactForm::form.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Return/Cform/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml

```
<form id="contact-form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl("cform/index/index")?>">
    <h3><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Order Information')) ?></h3>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <div class="field name">
            <label class="label" for="name"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Name')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="name" id="name" class="input-text" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field email">
            <label class="label" for="email"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="email" id="email" class="input-text" type="email" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field telephone">
            <label class="label" for="telephone"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Phone Number')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="telephone" id="telephone" class="input-text" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="field order_id">
            <label class="label" for="order_id"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Order ID')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="order_id" id="order_id" class="input-text" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>

         <h3><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product Information')) ?></h3>

        <div class="field product">
            <label class="label" for="product"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product Name')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="product" id="product" class="input-text" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field quantity">
            <label class="label" for="quantity"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Quantity')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="quantity" id="quantity" class="input-text" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="field comment">
            <label class="label" for="comment"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Reason for Return')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="input-text" cols="5" rows="2" ></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field opened">
            <label class="label"  for="comment"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product is opened')) ?></span></label>
             <div class="control">
              <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="opened" value="1"> Yes</label> &nbsp;
              <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="opened" value="0" checked="checked"> No</label>
            </div>
          </div>


        <?= $block->getChildHtml('form.additional.info') ?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <input type="hidden" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" />
            <button type="submit" id="add" title="" class="action submit primary">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Request Return')) ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
require(['jquery'],function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#add").click(function(){
        var customurl = "<?php echo $this->getUrl("cform/index/index") ?>";
        $.ajax({
            url: customurl,
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).closest('form').serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
        $('#contact-form')[0].reset(); 
        return false;
        });
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want your custom form at frontend or Backend?

Comment: I need at frontend, like feedback form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create layout XML

> /app/code/Company/Module/view/frontend/layout/module_index_custom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Company\Module\Block\Custom" name="customer_index_gallery" template="Vendor_Module::custom.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

> /app/code/Company/Module/Block/Custom.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Custom extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
       }

    /**
     * Get form action URL for POST booking request
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFormAction()
    {
        return '/companymodule/controller_name/custom';
        // here controller_name is index, action is booking
    }
}
```

> /app/code/Company/Module/view/frontend/templates/custom.phtml

```
<form action="<?php echo $block->getFormAction() ?>" method="post">
    <input name="firstname" type="text">
    <input name="lastname" type="text">
    <input name="email" type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="informations">
</form>
```

> /app/code/Company/Module/Controller/Index/Custom.php

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Custom extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * Booking action
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        // 1. POST request : Get booking data
        $post = (array) $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        if (!empty($post)) {
            // Retrieve your form data
            $firstname   = $post['firstname'];
            $lastname    = $post['lastname'];
            $email       = $post['email'];
          
            // Doing-something with...

            // Display the succes form validation message
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Booking done !');

            // Redirect to your form page (or anywhere you want...)
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $resultRedirect->setUrl('/companymodule/index/custom');

            return $resultRedirect;
        }
  
    }
}
```

Comment: Please let me noe file name for  "/app/code/Company/Module/Block"

Comment: Block file name Custom.php

Comment: Thanks for the list, i like to recive email after "informations submit"

Comment: get email in controller file      $email       = $post['email'];

Comment: i did not receive any email

Comment: call controller name correctly in block file.

Comment: return '/companymodule/controller_name/custom';

Comment: instred of "controller_name" what to do use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95001/discussion-between-msa-and-mohana).

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried to do the initial example that Priya shows but it has not worked for me, could you please tell me that I should correct it so that in my module from the backend it works for me?

Answer (score 0):

Here I show you the modified example given the characteristics of my module:

RealexPayments/HPP/Controller/Index/index.php

[image]

RealexPayments/HPP/etc/module.xml

[image]

RealexPayments/HPP/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

[image]

RealexPayments/HPP/Model/Cform.php

[image]

RealexPayments/HPP/Model/ResourceModel/Cform.php

[image]

RealexPayments/HPP/Model/ResourceModel/Cform/Collection.php

[image]

RealexPayments/HPP/view/adminhtml/layout/contactform_index_index.xml

[image]

RealexPayments/HPP/view/adminhtml/templates/form.phtml

[image]