# Contact Form in Magento 2 Custom Module is Not Sending Email

Tags: magento2, module, email, contact-form

I am currently trying to create a custom form in Magento 2.2.7. The purpose of this contact form is to provide our trade (wholesale) customers with a separate contact form to our retail customers (i.e. it will go to a seperate email to the main contact form).

I am using the method given in question [198838](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198838/how-to-create-a-custom-form-for-sending-email-with-file-attachment-in-magento-2/201816) to create this form. However when I click "Submit" nothing happens and in the Google developer console I get the following error:

> POST https://mysite.magedemo.co.uk/cform/index/index/ 500

[image]

My file system for this module is as follows:

[image]

My code is as follows:

> Controller > Index > Index.php

```
    <?php
    /**
     *
     * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    namespace Trading\Cform\Controller\Index;


    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
    use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;


    class Index extends Action
    {


         private $dataPersistor;
            /**
             * @return 

    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect|\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
         */

        protected $context;
        private $fileUploaderFactory;
        private $fileSy

stem;


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $_transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
     */
    protected $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */

     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        Filesystem $fileSystem,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Modia\Cform\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context,$transportBuilder,$inlineTranslation, $scopeConfig );
        $this->fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
        $this->fileSystem          = $fileSystem;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $filesData = $this->getRequest()->getFiles('upload_document');

        if ($filesData['name']) {
         $uploader = $this->fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'upload_document']);
         $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
         $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
         $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
         $path = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('test-doc');
         $result = $uploader->save($path);
         $upload_document = 'test-doc'.$uploader->getUploadedFilename();
         $filePath = $result['path'].$result['file'];
         $fileName = $result['name'];
    } else {
         $upload_document = '';
         $filePath = '';
         $fileName = '';
    }

        $txt='<table>';

        if($post['fname']){         
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Client Name</strong>:'.$post['fname'].'</td></tr>';          
        }
        if($post['address']){           
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Address</strong>:'.$post['address'].'</td></tr>';            
        }
        if($post['city']){
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>City</strong>:'.$post['city'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        if($post['state']){
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>State/Province</strong>:'.$post['state'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        if($post['zipcode']){
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Zip Code</strong>:'.$post['zipcode'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        if($post['phone']){
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Phone</strong>:'.$post['phone'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        if($post['email']){
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Email</strong>:'.$post['email'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        if(!empty($post['project_type'])){      
            $projecttypearray = implode(",",$post['project_type']);     
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Project Type</strong>:'.$projecttypearray.'</td></tr>';          
        }

        if($post['comment']){
            $txt.='<tr><td><strong>Comment</strong>:'.$post['comment'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        $txt.='</table>';
        //echo $txt;



        $customerName='Demo Form';
        $message=$txt;

        $userSubject= 'Demo From ';     
        $fromEmail= 'admin@gmail.com.com';
        $fromName = 'Test Demo Form';

         $templateVars = [
                    'store' => 1,
                    'customer_name' => $customerName,
                    'subject' => $userSubject,
                    'message'   => $message
                ];
        $from = ['email' => $fromEmail, 'name' => $fromName];
        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();


        $to = 'test@gmail.com';     

        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;

         $templateOptions = [
          'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
          'store' => 1
        ];

        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier(5, $storeScope)
                ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                ->setFrom($from)
                ->addTo($to)
                ->addAttachment($filePath, $fileName)               
                ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();

        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Form successfully submitted'));

        $this->_redirect('form');
    }

}
```

> Magento > Mail > Template > TransportBuilder.php

```
<?php
namespace Trading\Cform\Magento\Mail\Template;

class TransportBuilder extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{
    public function addAttachment($file, $name)
    {
        if (!empty($file) && file_exists($file)) {
            $this->message
            ->createAttachment(
                file_get_contents($file),
                \Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
                \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                basename($name)
            );
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

> Model > ResourceModel > Cform > Collection.php

```
<?php
namespace Trading\Cform\Model\ResourceModel\Cform;

use \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{

    protected $_idFieldName = \Trading\Cform\Model\Cform::CONTECT_ID;

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Trading\Cform\Model\Cform', 'Trading\Cform\Model\ResourceModel\Cform');
    }

}
```

> Model > ResourceModel > Cform.php

```
<?php

namespace Trading\Cform\Model\ResourceModel;

class Cform extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    protected $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        $connectionName = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $connectionName);
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('trading_contect', 'contect_id');
    }
}
```

> Model > Cform.php

```
<?php

namespace Trading\Cform\Model;

class Cform extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Trading\Cform\Model\ResourceModel\Cform');
    }

}
```

> Setup > InstallSchema.php

```
<?php
namespace Trading\Cform\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        /**
         * Create table 'vendor_contect'
         */
        $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
            $installer->getTable('trading_contect')
        )->addColumn(
            'contect_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'Contect Id'
        )->addColumn(
            'name',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Name'
        )->addColumn(
            'email',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Email Id'
        )->addColumn(
            'telephone',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['nullable'=> false],
            'Phone Number'
        )->addColumn(
            'comment',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'What's on your mind?'
        );
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
    }
}
```

> etc > frontend > routes.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="cform" frontName="cform">
            <module name="Trading_Cform" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> etc > di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" type="\Trading\Cform\Magento\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" />
</config>
```

> etc > module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Trading_Cform" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

> view > frontend > templates > form.phtml

```
<form id="contact-form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl("cform/index/index")?>">
    <h1><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Contact Form')) ?></h1>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <div class="field name">
            <label class="label" for="name"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Name')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="name" id="name" class="input-text" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field email">
            <label class="label" for="email"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="email" id="email" class="input-text" type="email" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field telephone">
            <label class="label" for="telephone"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Phone Number')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="telephone" id="telephone" class="input-text" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field comment">
            <label class="label" for="comment"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('What�s on your mind?')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="input-text" cols="5" rows="3" ></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('form.additional.info') ?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <input type="hidden" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" />
            <button type="submit" id="add" title="" class="action submit primary">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Submit')) ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>


<script>
require(['jquery'],function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#add").click(function(){
        var customurl = "<?php echo $this->getUrl("cform/index/index") ?>";
        $.ajax({
            url: customurl,
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).closest('form').serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
        $('#contact-form')[0].reset(); 
        return false;
        });
    });
}); 
</script>
```

> registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Trading_Cform',
    __DIR__
);
```

If someone could advise me on what I am doing wrong here I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Did you want to create new form page or additional fields in contact us page?

Comment: A new form page

Comment: Try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/278541/60921

Comment: Did you get solution?

Comment: I've implemented the solution and I'm not getting the error anymore but it's not displaying the 'Booking done' Message or sending any emails.

Comment: Did you create router file?

Comment: The routes.xml file? Yes.

Comment: Did you create form successfully?

Comment: Are you have issue in email send? Am i correct?

Comment: I've created both forms from the page you linked (the question and answer). The Question form gives the following error when submit is clicked "jquery.js:10254 POST https://mysite.magedemo.co.uk/tform/index/index/ 404". The Solution form gives no error when clicked but nothing else seems to happen although there is a message which states "JQMIGRATE: Logging is active"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With much thanks to [MSA](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/60921/msa) for pointing me in the right direction. I've now created a working form based on a few previously asked questions but in particular [125478](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125478/how-to-create-custom-form-in-magento2-frontend):

The file system now looks as follows:

[image]

All of these files are placed in the following location:

> App > Code > Trade > Tform

First the registration file:

> registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Trade_Tform',
    __DIR__
);
```

> Block > Tcontact.php

```
 <?php

namespace Trade\Tform\Block;

class Tcontact extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
       }

    /**
     * Get form action URL for POST booking request
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFormAction()
    {
            // tradetform is given in routes.xml
            // controller_name is folder name inside controller folder
            // action is php file name inside above controller_name folder

        return '/tradetform/index/tcontact';
        // here controller_name is index, action is tcontact
    }
}
```

> Controller > Index > Tcontact.php

```
<?php

namespace Trade\Tform\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Tcontact extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * Booking action
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        // 1. POST request : Get booking data
        $post = (array) $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        if (!empty($post)) {

            // Retrieve your form data
            $name    = $post['name'];
            $email   = $post['email'];
            $phone   = $post['phone'];
            $comment = $post['comment'];
            $messagetitle = "Enquiry From Custom Contact Form";
            $messagecontent = 
            $messagetitle."\n"."\n".
            "name: ".$name."\n"."\n".
            "email: ".$email."\n"."\n".
            "phone: ".$phone."\n"."\n".
            "comment: ".$comment."\n";

            // Send email to the following specified address
            mail("emailaddress@emailprovider.com","Trade Enquiry",$messagecontent);
            // Display the succes form validation message
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Message Sent!');

            // Redirect to your form page (or anywhere you want...)
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $resultRedirect->setUrl('/page-that-form-is-on');

            return $resultRedirect;
        }
        // 2. GET request : Render the booking page 
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

> etc > frontend > routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="tradetform" frontName="tradetform">
            <module name="Trade_Tform"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> etc > module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Trade_Tform" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

> view > frontend > layout > tradetform_index_tcontact.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Trade Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Trade\Tform\Block\Tcontact" name="tradetform.tcontact" template="Trade_Tform::tcontact.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> view > frontend > templates > tcontact.phtml

```
<form action="<?php echo $block->getFormAction() ?>" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}' method="post">
    <p>Contact Name  <span style=" color: #e02b27; font-size: 1.2rem;">*</span>
    <input name="name" type="text" data-validate='{"required":true}'></p>
    <p>Contact Email <span style=" color: #e02b27; font-size: 1.2rem;">*</span>
    <input name="email" type="text" data-validate='{"required":true}'></p>
    <p>Contact Phone
    <input name="phone" type="text"></p>
    <p>Message
    <textarea name="comment" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

After this it was a case of running the upgrade command in CLI.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: congrats @CJNOtts

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

create layout file

> view/frontend/layout/cform_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Trading\Cform\Block\Custom" name="customer_index_gallery" template="Trading_Cform::form.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

Controller file

> Controller\Index\Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Trading\Cform\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->_pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

> view/frontend/templates/form.phtml

```
<form action="<?php echo $block->getFormAction() ?>" method="post">
    <input name="firstname" type="text">
    <input name="lastname" type="text">
    <input name="email" type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="informations">
</form>
```

> /app/codeTrading/Cform/Block

```
<?php

namespace Trading\Cform\Block;

class Custom extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
       }

    /**
     * Get form action URL for POST booking request
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFormAction()
    {
        return '/cform/index/index';
        // here controller_name is index, action is booking
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this @CJNotts

Comment: Thanks. Could you let me know the file paths that I need to create those files in please?

Comment: I updated file path

Comment: Hi. That seems to be doing something now at least. I'm getting the message "Navigated to https://mysite.magedemo.co.uk/test-page
jquery-migrate.js:21 JQMIGRATE: Logging is active" 

I'm guessing now that I just have to specify that I want it to send the form details to an email address?

Comment: mysite.magedemo.co.uk/cform/index/index

Comment: Hi, Your URL  need be like this

Comment: Hi. Same thing: "Navigated to https://mysite.magedemo.co.uk/cform/index/index
jquery-migrate.js:21 JQMIGRATE: Logging is active".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95497/discussion-between-msa-and-cjnotts).